# ExoPlayer play multiple videos simultaneously

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am building a video player android application where I need to play 2(maybe 4) live streams at the same time in the same view. [image: Sample UI]

Is it possible using a single exoplayer instance? If yes, please suggest how, also how to handle audio as I only need to play audio from a single stream. If no, then how should I proceed with it?

Thank you

Comment: This seems like a pretty advanced use-case if you need to achieve it. Simpler solution would be to use multiple PlayerViews which although might end up being resource heavy.

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4880) and [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2855)

Comment: AS @che10 says it sounds like it would be easier to have separate ExoPlayer instances, and I am not sure if would really be that much more overhead as each stream has to be decoded and displayed either way. Maybe there is some reason you need it combined into a single video?

Comment: Anything else you may suggest me? 
Any possibility working with renders?